# No ghc or ghci commands after installing in Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, installation

I downloaded HaskellPlatform-core setup file from [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) and installed it.

The installation process went all right but on trying in a terminal, there is no command ghc or ghci. There are commands runghc and runhaskell, but they give error:

```
runghc: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\bin\ghc-stage2.exe: rawSystem: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

The bin directory contains following files:

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\bin

12-09-2019  12:39    <DIR>          .
12-09-2019  12:39    <DIR>          ..
23-04-2019  11:28                 0 haddock.exe
23-04-2019  11:28           442,498 hp2ps.exe
23-04-2019  11:28        20,918,891 hpc.exe
23-04-2019  11:28        19,891,856 hsc2hs.exe
23-04-2019  11:28        16,968,286 runghc.exe
23-04-2019  11:28        16,968,286 runhaskell.exe
               6 File(s)     75,189,817 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,848,975,360 bytes free
```

ghc.exe and ghci.exe are not there. Also there is no file named ghc-stage2.exe in any of the directories under HaskellPlatform.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: The path automatically added by setup program includes:

```
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\lib\extralibs\bin;
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\bin
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\mingw\bin
```

Comment: Since Haskell platform comes with `stack`, you can just use `stack ghci` to invoke ghci. But, I would just directly use stack directly: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/#how-to-install

Comment: But simple Windows install should work perfectly.

Comment: Normally they are in `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\bin`. Try to reinstall.